# Result: Failure Exception: AttributeError: 'Engine' object has no attribute 'execute' Azure Functions

Tags: python, sql, azure, sqlalchemy, azure-functions

I am quite new to Azure Functions. This code for some reason runs locally but when deployed to an Azure Function, give this error.

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, event
import textwrap
import base64
import pandas as pd
import logging
import pyodbc

def sql_run_query(data_base,service_date):
    driver = '{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}'
    server_name = **********************************
    database_name = data_base
    server='{server_name},1433'.format(server_name=server_name)
    username = **********************************
    password = **********************************
    connection_string=textwrap.dedent('''Driver={driver};Server={server};Database={database};Uid={username};Pwd={password};Encrypt=yes;TrustServerCertificate=no;Connection Timeout=30;'''.format(driver=driver,server=server,database=database_name,username=username,password=password))
    engine = create_engine('mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect='+connection_string)
    #engine =create_sql_engine(data_base)
    engine.execute('declare @service_date_var as varchar(100) = '+service_date+'delete from [dbo].[performance] where service_date = @service_date_var')
    logging.info(f"query in {data_base} run succesfully")
    print(f"query in {data_base} run succesfully")
```

Result: Failure Exception: AttributeError: 'Engine' object has no attribute 'execute' Stack: File "/azure-functions-host/workers/python/3.9/LINUX/X64/azure_functions_worker/dispatcher.py", line 452, in _handle__invocation_request call_result = await self._loop.run_in_executor( File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 58, in run result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs) File "/azure-functions-host/workers/python/3.9/LINUX/X64/azure_functions_worker/dispatcher.py", line 718, in _run_sync_func return ExtensionManager.get_sync_invocation_wrapper(context, File "/azure-functions-host/workers/python/3.9/LINUX/X64/azure_functions_worker/extension.py", line 215, in _raw_invocation_wrapper result = function(**args) File "/home/site/wwwroot/BlobTrigger2/**init**.py", line 40, in main sql_run_query('kad_smc',dte) File "/home/site/wwwroot/sql_uploader/sql_uploader.py", line 74, in sql_run_query engine.execute('''

Can someone explain the reason for this and a possible fix?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [deprecated](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/connections.html#sqlalchemy.engine.Engine.execute) `execute` method of `engine` has been removed in SQLAlchemy 2.0.  You need to ensure that you are running the same version of SQLAlchemy in both environments and consider [migrating](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/changelog/migration_20.html) to v2.0.

Comment: What if we downgrade the SQLAlchemy to 1.4 ? Will it fix the issue ?

Comment: @Robin I would expect so.